# How to initialize with same weights in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am building a CNN model with tensorflow and I wanted to know if it is possible to set somehow a seed for weights initialization in order to be able to have everywhere the same seed so that I can compare between different architectures of my model. Found answers on stack overflow like this [Tensorflow weight initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489697/tensorflow-weight-initialization) but didn't really help me so your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the **`kernel_initializer`** in all the layers as per your requirement. The term kernel_initializer is a fancy term for which statistical distribution or function is used for initialising the weights.

The initializer can take different values. You can set them all zeros, ones or a constant value. You can also choose RandomUniform or RandomNormal with the seed value.

If you are using tensorflow for layer, then you can find details about different initializers here - [Tensorflow Initialzer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers)

If you are using Keras for layer, then you can find details about different initializers here - [Keras Initializer](https://keras.io/initializers/)

Comment: Thank you! But anyways I think that won't work right? Because everytime the data are shuffled so the order of images is shuffled and the batches change so again I can't make a comparison with another architecture, can I?

Comment: You can compare different architecture if you are using same seed for shuffling the data. The shuffled data will always be the same for particular seed. So make sure you are using same data with same seed for all the architecture.

Comment: @Ponx - If I have answered your question, can you please accept the answer and upvote the answer. Thank You.