# Is it a good practise to initialize weights before to train a Neural Network? (in order to reduce randomness)

Tags: neural-network

I know that every time a neural network is trained, it is not possible to obtain exaclty the same result. So, I would like to reduce as much as possible the randomness. Is it a good practise to initialize weights before to train a Neural Network? There are some suggestions that I should follow when I write a code?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Why does my question receive-1?

Answer (score 1):

Weights are **always** initialized before training. There are multiple weight initialization methods. For example:

- Random initialization
- Zero initialization
  Using zero initialization would solve your problem. However, it is not used in practice, because zero initialization essentially turns the neural network into a linear model. You have to use random initialization.

You can, however, initialize weights randomly, using the same **seed.** Here is an example using Keras API:

```
init_1 = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed=1)
layer_1 = layers.Dense(
    units=64,
    kernel_initializer=init_1
)

init_2 = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed=2)
layer_2 = layers.Dense(
    units=2,
    kernel_initializer=init_2
)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([layer_1, layer_2])
```

This code creates a 2-layered DNN. Weights of each layer is initialized with a different seed (so that they will not be equal to each other), but they will be same (with themselves), if initialized again.

Have a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60881649/11919175), and [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/how-to-initialize-weights-in-neural-networks/).